# Multi items app in Android

Tags: android, button, menu, android-activity

I want to create android app that contains 5 or 6 options on menu page. And when I click on any menu option other activity starts and each activity related to menu option contain 5 or 6 option to start other activities. I am using buttons for menu options. But its very difficult to create 25 to 36 activities. Is there any way to make it easy?

My problem is-

Activity1-

```
Option1
Option2
Option3
Option4
Option5
```

On any option click new activity start i.e on click on option1 activity 2 starts and it contains-

```
Option6
Option7
Option8
Option9
Option10
```

And on click on `option6` some description.

So according to this way I have to create 30 activity classes very time consuming. Is there any easy way to do this?

Comment: are the activity layouts identical in design?

Comment: @JustinSlade yes layouts are identical. so I am using only one layout.

Answer (score 0):

Use Slide menu for page change.
and on page use tabview that's good choice

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please add more details. Your reply is a (maybe) good starting point, but not enough to answer the question

Answer (score 0):

You could use a grid view or list view and alter the dataset depending on where you are.